# Docker XeLaTeX arara no error msg

Tags: xetex, arara

When I compile my LaTeX Document locally with arara it works! But when I put it into Docker (Fedora) I only get this Emergeny-stop:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.10.21)  22 OCT 2020 00:31
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**thesis.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> thesis.tex

End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2 strings out of 494894
 16 string characters out of 6177061
 56151 words of memory out of 5000000
 4029 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
~                                                                                                                                                                                                
~
```

texput.log:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'thesis.tex' (size: 9 KB, last modified: 10/21/2020
21:07:49), please wait.

(Clean) Cleaning feature ................................ SUCCESS
(Clean) Cleaning feature ................................ SUCCESS
(Clean) Cleaning feature ................................ SUCCESS
(Clean) Cleaning feature ................................ SUCCESS
(Clean) Cleaning feature ................................ SUCCESS
(XeLaTeX) XeLaTeX engine ................................ FAILURE

Total: 0.78 seconds
```

I tried to install full TexLive, to get sure I've all packages installed, but it did not work.
It looks like batch mode (no error msg) so I tried:
% arara: xelatex: { interaction: errorstopmode }

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: clean: {files: [thesis.pdfsync, thesis.bbl, thesis.aux, thesis.toc, thesis.pdf]}
% arara: xelatex: { interaction: errorstopmode }
% arara: nomencl
% arara: biber
% arara: biber
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { interaction: errorstopmode }
% arara: xelatex: { interaction: errorstopmode }
% arara: clean: {files: [thesis.pdfsync, thesis.out, thesis.toc, thesis.lot, thesis.lof, thesis.bbl, thesis.nls, thesis.nlo, thesis.aux, thesis.idx, thesis.ilg, thesis.ind, thesis.bbl, thesis.bcf, thesis.ist, thesis.blg, thesis.run.xml, thesis.fdb_latexmk, thesis.fls]}
```

Comment: You should always run arara with `-l` and `-v` to get a log and verbose output if errors occur. How did you invoke the Docker command (especially concerning inclusion of the files and working directory)? Maybe https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive/-/wikis/Building-LaTeX-documents-locally-using-Docker helps to debug your process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TeXnician with `arara -lv` i was able to produce a log and error massages and solved the underlying problems, at the end there where a couple of missing packages and missing files in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are two things happening here: first, the thesis file is not being found. Then xelatex is being run in batch mode so that an attempt to read from the terminal is failing.

The tipoff to this is the fact that the log file is named `texput.log` and not `thesis.log`